# 2008 R2 - will not respond to keybd/mouse after firewall change nor RDP [RESOLVED]

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

**SYSTEM:**
Windows 2008 R2 Server running really well for some time as both file server on a local network [Workgroup] and a Webserver on port 80.

**PROBLEM:**
1: Ctrl-Alt-Del log-in not recognised. Cannot log in.
2: Remote Desktop has stopped working.

Keyboard and mouse hardware both USB and checked as working fine.
During Boot the keyboard is fine in the pre-OS phase for pausing and resuming BIOS load.

I.e: If the server had a forced power-down, the resulting "Your system didn't close correctly" screen offers "Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Network, Last known good Windows" etc options and the keyboard works fine here.

When presented with the log-in screen, Ctrl Alt Del does nothing. There is no response to the keyboard [or others tried].

Plugging USB disk units in fire up fine on USB channels

**RECENT CHANGES THAT MIGHT AFFECT:**
Remote Desktop on the local network was working fine. Using it I changed the server firewall to restrict RD TCP-In rules to Local IP Addresses only.

I tried to leave Remote IP address entry blank after selecting "These IP addresses" [as opposed to 'All'] but it wouldn't allow it so I added "1.1.1.1"   thinking that would act as a dummy entry. [*Possibly this is my BIG mistake!!!*"]

Now I cannot access Remote Desktop from another PC on the local network either so I am unable to access the server either across the network or locally.

The only Port Forwarding in the router setup is Port 80 to Port 80

Thank you for reading this - any kind guidance will be greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**   Firstly, sincere thanks for the really kind responses!

I had forgotten to add that Malwarebytes had just been loaded prior to this issue.

For the benefit of anyone with a similar problem;

- Using Safe Mode at **boot time** [F8] I was able to boot the machine into a state to accept keybd/mouse entry to log-on.
- Attempt to access Firewall in any way as Administrator revealed the security snap-in had failed to load.
- Sudden recollection that Malwarebytes had been loaded. This was removed and a full reboot ensued.
- TOTAL access after full reboot! Log-in working but RDP not.
- Reverted the Firewall RDP Incoming rules to accept any IP, internal or external.

Remote Desktop now working.

Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: So do you have physical access to that machine or not?

Comment: Have you tried Safe mode?  (note the 1.1.1.1 entry seems innocuous.)

Comment: duenni: Yes I do have physical access

Comment: uSlackr - Have tried Safe Mode at boot time - works!!! Previously tried safe Mode at the earlier mention failed boot screen and that didn't.